# How do I can extend the Ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

Okay, I've already allocate 30GB to extend the Ubuntu partition, but I can't extend it from GParted

[gparted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pem5F.png)

[ubuntu partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9E99.png)

How I can extend it? Should I use the live CD?

Comment: Yes you can! Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry mate, you're not gonna be able to extend your root partition into that unallocated space. You can only extend partitions into unallocated space that are next to each other (or when spanning across multiple disks). In this case only `dev/sda5` or `/dev/sda6` will be able to use that space. Your only options are to add another drive and migrate your ubuntu instance to that, or delete `sda6` and `sda7` and then extend that way. Deleting `sda6` isn't a big deal, it's just a swap partition. `sda7` is a hidden Windows part, probably a boot or recovery partition. Unless you know exactly what that partition is, and you aren't afraid to lose any of that data, I would advise against messing with it.

Comment: So the unallocated partition should be next to  the ubuntu partition?

Comment: Unfortunately that is the case

Comment: Do you have any idea to move the sda7? sda7 is a windows recovery partition anyway. I'm thinking to move unallocated to the left side of windows partition and clone the recovery partition to it.

Comment: If you have a clone of the partition already, i would delete sda6, boot into Windows, extend the recovery partition to fill the unallocated space, defrag it (probably using a third party like defraggler because they're more effective than the native Win one) to try and align all the data to the front of the disk. Assuming that works you could then shrink the recovery partition back down to its original size and the unallocated space would now be between the recovery partition and your root partition. extended your root partition, making sure to leave enough space to rebuild your swap partition

Comment: if defragging the recovery partition doesn't work, and you have an known good clone of it, delete it, extend your root partition (once again leaving room for your swap) and then boot into windows, shrink your c partition to make enough space for the recovery partition and then rebuild it.